# pass parametes from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

Why when I turn to servlet  the design is broken after Refresh, but in  jsp file is not broken.

Why when I send a submit form from jsp , the data validation in JavaScript and then sent to servlet, but when I came from the servlet controller to this page. the link is not .jsp and then the data is not sent , and submit work without validation

Comment: And now in English please?

Comment: Any relevant code to go with this?